# Version history/ revisioning

Tags: nodes

Is there a way to get drupal 7 to keep version history for every node/page without having to remember to select the "Create new revision" option every single time?

Is there a module that improves this feature? Also, the ability to Diff two different revisions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set each content type to default to create a new revision; if you edit a content type you'll see something like this:

[image]

Select the 'Create new revision' checkbox and save the form; when you add/edit content of that type the 'Create new revision' option will be pre-selected.

As far as diffing revisions goes, you can install the [Diff module](http://drupal.org/project/diff):

> This module adds a tab for sufficiently permissioned users. The tab shows all revisions like standard Drupal but it also allows pretty viewing of all added/changed/deleted words between revisions.